# Как у списка ListView отключить стандартные сепараторы (разделители)?

Tags: android, listview, java

Добрый день!
Скажите, пожалуйста, как у `ListView` отключить стандартные полосы подчеркивающие каждый итем?
Гуглил, но ничего не нашел!
Особо не ругайте! Может я еще гуглить не научился)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:divider="@color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Привет, добро пожаловать на SO на Русском. А это решение существенно отличается от соседнего ответа? Вроде бы там почти то же самое.

Comment: свойство цвета(color) transparent только в системных цветах. если написать так как написано выше, будет ошибка. Так как такого параметра в color нет. поэтому необходимо дописать приставочку @android: